# Distinguishing Primitive vs. Nonprimitive Roots of Unity

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

In a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359367/minimal-polynomials-of-sin-pi-8-and-cos-pi-9#_=_), the solution given states that
$$\zeta=\cos{(\pi/8)}+i\sin{(\pi/8)}$$
is a primitive 8th root of unity.  I was under the impression that the primitive roots of unity were given by
$$\zeta_n=\cos{(2\pi/n)}+i\sin{(2\pi/n)}$$
which in case wouldn't it be a primitive 16th root of unity?   I might have my language messed up here, so I was just looking for clarification.

Comment: I agree with you. $\cos(\pi/8)+i\sin(\pi/8)$ is a primitive sixteenth root of unity.

Comment: I was lookiing up ways to determine how to find minimal polynomials for sin(k) where k is in degrees, so I came across that answer and the language confused me for a second.  I haven't even gone forward to determine whether the question is right or wrong now, but thank you for clarifying.

Comment: If $n\gt 2$, there are several primitive roots of unity. A complete list is given by the numbers $\cos(2k\pi/n)+i\sin(2k\pi/n)$, where $k$ ranges over all integers $k$ such that $1\le k\le n-1$ and $k$ and $n$ are relatively prime. The number $\cos(\pi/8))+i\sin(\pi/8)$ is not one of them.

Comment: That is what I thought, i was under the assumption of the coprimality, but just referenced the first for the problem mentioned.  Thanks for the clarification, @AndréNicolas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me illustrate in case of $4$th roots of unity. Well $x^4=1$ has 4 roots $1, i, -i , -1$ and out of these four $i  \; \mbox{and} -i$ have a special property that $i^k \neq 1$ if $k<4$ that means they are strictly fourth roots of unity and no smaller power of these numbers is 1.